# Get count of day types between two dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying the get the count of week days between two dates for which I have not found the solution in BigQuery standard sql. I have tried the BQ sql date function `DATE_DIFF(date_expression_a, date_expression_b, date_part)` following published examples, but it did not reveal the result.

For example, I have two dates `2021-02-13` and `2021-03-31` and my desired outcome would be:

| MON | TUE | WED | THUR | FRI | SAT | SUN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 7 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with your_table as (
  select date
  from unnest(generate_date_array("2021-02-13", "2021-03-30")) AS date  
)
select * from your_table
pivot (count(*) for format_date('%a', date) in ('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'))
```

with output

[image]

Or you can just simply do

```
select 
  format_date('%a', date) day_of_week, 
  count(*) counts
from your_table
group by day_of_week
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK
  FROM
    dates)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'TUE'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'THU'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'SAT'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'SUN'
END
  AS day_of_week,
  COUNT(*) AS day_count
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2021-02-13", "2021-03-30")) AS dates
GROUP BY 1
```

The important part is the `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function, that will return all the dates between the dates you're interested in. `UNNEST` will return one row for each date (instead of one row for the array of all dates).

From there, you can extract the day of the week thanks to the BQ date functions, and count the number of occurences with a `GROUP BY` day_of_week.

The above query gives the following result:

[image]